# Select 40 most recent sales from each neighborhood group MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know this is probably really close to a lot of other questions, but I've been looking at examples on here all day and haven't been able to get exactly what I need.

I have a table called `Sales` that has columns `PARID, PRICE, SALEDT, SALEVAL, NBHD`, and `ID` in it. I need the records that have the 40 most recent `SALEDT` for each `NBHD`. `ID` is the only completely unique identifier for each row. I'm doing this in an MS Access database by the way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select top (40) t2.id
               from t as t2
               where t2.nbhd = t.nbhd
               order by t2.saledt desc, t2.id
              );
```

Comment: That works well, thank you. Now what if I wanted to do this by `PARID`? `PARID` will have a few duplicate entries here and there, and I only want the most recent `SALEDT` for that `PARID`. Same basic top 40 idea though.

Comment: @Jsqsh  . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.